# Estimating Parameters of a Custom Distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, distributions

The problem is I can not get estimation of parameters of any custom probability distribution (distributions are not built in Mathematica), here is an example:

**First**: I entered random numbers of custom distribution (I entered the PDF of Weibull distribution) and I want its parameters to be estimated then I have an infinite loop somewhere, and the program runs for hours on a relatively fast machine, without producing anything..the steps on Mathematica are:

```
custom[a_, b_] := ProbabilityDistribution[(a/b) ((x/b)^(a - 1)) E^-(x/b)^a, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]
PDF[custom[a, b]]
W = RandomVariate[custom[2, 3], 50]
FindDistributionParameters[W, custom[a, b]]
```

**Second**: I entered the same steps but I replace final step with
`FindDistributionParameters[W, WeibullDistribution[a, b]]`. I got the answer in one second

> ```
> {a -> 1.99144, b -> 2.6355}
> ```

The problem is if the custom distribution is not built in Mathematica what will be happened to estimate its parameters???

Comment: On second thoughts: How does this question differ from your first one: [How to estimate parameters of a custom distribution?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61373/how-to-estimate-parameters-of-a-custom-distribution)?

Comment: Dear Yves Keltt the main idea not on mathimatical properties as it was commented before..the main idea on Mathematica coding language..i  illustrate my point on this example.

Comment: Dear Momo,  I am not entirely sure about the difference between the questions. Hopefully the answer here can help you,  otherwise please edit the original one to reflect the differences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear[custom];
```

When defining the custom distribution, include the parameter assumptions required for the custom distribution to be a valid distribution.

```
custom[a_, b_] = ProbabilityDistribution[
   (a/b) ((x/b)^(a - 1)) E^-(x/b)^a, {x, 0, Infinity},
   Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0];

DistributionParameterAssumptions[custom[a, b]]
```

> a > 0 && b > 0

```
W = RandomVariate[custom[2, 3], 50];

FindDistributionParameters[W, custom[a, b]]
```

> {a -> 2.11554, b -> 3.11318}

```
FindDistributionParameters[W, WeibullDistribution[a, b]]
```

> {a -> 2.11554, b -> 3.11318}

As expected, the parameters are identical since

```
PDF[custom[a, b], x] == PDF[WeibullDistribution[a, b], x]
```

> True

Comment: it works goo
Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

Estimates of parameters deserve estimates of precision.  Unfortunately, `FindDistributionParameters` doesn't provide that.  However, it is relatively easy to do in *Mathematica*.

```
(* Generate data *)
SeedRandom[12345];
W = RandomVariate[custom[2, 3], 50];

(* Maximum likelihood estimates of parameters *)
mle = FindDistributionParameters[W, custom[a, b]]
(* {a -> 2.68137, b -> 2.85603} *)

(* Log of the likelihood *)
logL = LogLikelihood[custom[a, b], W];

(* Covariance matrix of parameter estimators *)
cov = -Inverse[D[logL, {{a, b}, 2}] /. mle]
(* {{0.0900731, 0.0148357}, {0.0148357, 0.0251339}} *)

(* Standard errors of estimators of a and b, respectively *)
stdErrs = Sqrt[Diagonal[cov]]
(* {0.300122, 0.158537} *)

(* Correlation between estimators of a and b *)
abCorrelation = cov[[1, 2]]/Sqrt[cov[[1, 1]] cov[[2, 2]]]
(* 0.311804 *)
```