# FindDistributionParameters fails with custom distribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, estimation

**Context**

I would like to find the [`MaximumLikelihood`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaximumLikelihood.html) solution
of a customized PDF

Let's start with a built in PDF. Following the documentation

```
dat = RandomVariate[LaplaceDistribution[2, 1], 1000];
param=FindDistributionParameters[dat, LaplaceDistribution[μ, σ],
 ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood", Method -> "NMaximize"}]
```

(*  {μ->2.27258,σ->0.521354} *)

```
Show[Plot[
PDF[LaplaceDistribution[μ, σ] /. param, x], {x, -5, 5}], 
Histogram[dat, Automatic, "PDF"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

works as expected. It finds a good estimator of $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

**The problem**

Now let me do the same with a customized PDF.
Here I just impose that my custom PDF cannot be evaluated before it
is given numerical values.

```
Clear[myLaplaceDistribution];
myLaplaceDistribution[μ_?NumberQ, σ_?NumberQ] := 
 LaplaceDistribution[μ, σ]
```

Then

```
dat = RandomVariate[LaplaceDistribution[2, 1], 10];
FindDistributionParameters[dat, myLaplaceDistribution[μ, σ],
 ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood", Method -> "NMaximize"}]
```

does not return a maximum likelihood estimate.

I am using 10.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (October 9, 2015)

**Question:**

> Any suggestions on how to make `FindDistributionParameters` work with unevaluated PDFs?

PS: I am aware of this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107914/1089 but here this question is a bit more general than simply a transformed distribution? And I have tried

```
dat = RandomVariate[LaplaceDistribution[2, 1], 10];
FindDistributionParameters[dat, 
 myLaplaceDistribution[μ, σ], {{μ, 
   Mean[dat]}, {σ, Mean[dat]}},
 ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood", Method -> "NMaximize"}]
```

it does not seems to help.

**Update**

This related answer
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61426/1089
does not seem to help.

If I define explicitly the domain for the PDF

```
  Clear[myLaplaceDistribution2];
  myLaplaceDistribution2[μ_?NumberQ, σ_?NumberQ] := 
  ProbabilityDistribution[
  PDF[LaplaceDistribution[μ, σ], x], {x, -Infinity, 
   Infinity}, Assumptions -> (μ ∈ Reals && σ > 0)]
```

It still fails

```
dat = RandomVariate[LaplaceDistribution[2, 1], 10];
FindDistributionParameters[dat, 
 myLaplaceDistribution2[μ, σ], {{μ, 
   Mean[dat]}, {σ, Mean[dat]}},
 ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood", Method -> "NMaximize"}]
```

As @J.M. points out one can use the fact that Mathematica can cope with the fact the PDF need not be normalized. As follows

```
Clear[myLaplaceDistribution3];
myLaplaceDistribution3[μ_, σ_] = 
 ProbabilityDistribution[
  2 PDF[LaplaceDistribution[μ, σ], 
    x], {x, -∞, ∞}, 
  Assumptions -> (μ ∈ Reals && σ > 0), 
  Method -> "Normalize"]
```

(Note the factor of 2 in front of `PDF` to make the PDF not normalized.)

Then

```
dat = RandomVariate[LaplaceDistribution[2, 1], 10];
FindDistributionParameters[dat, myLaplaceDistribution3[μ, σ],
 ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood"}]
```

works.

> I still think there must be situations where the PDF cannot be known before
>   its arguments are known, and where Maximum likelihood analysis would make sense?

Note that I can always make my own:

```
MyFindDistributionParameters[data_, distrib_, var_] :=
 NMaximize[{Total[Log@ PDF[distrib, #] & /@ data], 
   DistributionParameterAssumptions[distrib]}, var][[2]];

MyFindDistributionParameters[dat,LaplaceDistribution[μ, σ], {μ, σ}]
```

but I was hoping Mathematica would provide me with a more efficient algorithm?
(this seems to be 10 times slower than the built in function).

Comment: Have you tried using `ProbabilityDistribution[]` instead to express your custom distribution?

Comment: @J.M. just tried while you commented. Seem to produce the same. The reason I want to have a delayed definition is that in real life my PDF is not normalized so I need to normalize it via numerical integration.

Comment: Well, `ProbabilityDistribution[]` supports the setting `Method -> "Normalize"` so that the normalization is done on your behalf.

Comment: Ah! That might be a lead then. The question remains of interest?

Comment: Somehow, I feel that the `NumericQ[]` is interfering with any symbolic attempts being done under the hood. In any event, you should have used `ProbabilityDistribution[]` like this: `ProbabilityDistribution[Piecewise[{{Exp[-(x - μ)/σ], x >= μ}}, Exp[-(-x + μ)/σ]], {x, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> (μ ∈ Reals && σ > 0), Method -> "Normalize"]`; note the specification of assumptions, and that the (not necessarily normalized) PDF expression itself should be the first argument.

Comment: [Related.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84265/finddistributionparameters-gives-an-error-for-a-mixture-of-user-defined-sinh-arc)

Comment: Just to be clear about @J.M. 's comment:  removing `?NumberQ` makes all of your examples work.

Comment: @JimBaldwin yes but it defeats the purpose. What if I am in a situation where my PDF cannot be known a priori, before mu and sigma have a numerical value?

Comment: Clearly I don't understand your purpose.  Giving mu and sigma to `FindDistributionParameters` without giving them numbers is essential.  What is it about having your second example work when removing `?NumberQ` doesn't work for you?  (I'm not trying to be sarcastic.  I'm just clearly missing something.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow @J.M. 's advice removing `?NumberQ` from the definition of the probability distribution makes everything work fine:

```
Clear[myLaplaceDistribution];
SeedRandom[12345];
myLaplaceDistribution[μ_, σ_] := LaplaceDistribution[μ, σ]
dat = RandomVariate[LaplaceDistribution[2, 1], 10];
FindDistributionParameters[dat, myLaplaceDistribution[μ, σ],
 ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood", Method -> "NMaximize"}]
(* {μ -> 1.8804870321227085,σ -> 0.7153183538699862} *)
```

I don't know what you mean by "Here I just impose that my custom PDF cannot be evaluated before it is given numerical values."  Your first example doesn't have the two parameters evaluated as numbers and it works fine:

```
param=FindDistributionParameters[dat, LaplaceDistribution[μ, σ],
 ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood", Method -> "NMaximize"}]
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I guess I have simplified too much the original problem. In my case the model PDF is the result of a convolved calculation which requires that mu and sigma are numerical. I tried to mimic this by stating that myLaplaceDistribution requires numerical values before it can be evaluated. So your answer solves the posed problem but not my problem.

Comment: I look forward to the new question.