# FindDistributionParameters fails with custom distribution which cannot be evaluated symbolically

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

**Context**

I am interested in measuring the dark energy equation of state  of the universe while fitting the PDF of density in cells.
This involves fitting a one parameter PDF to some data.

---

Following this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133392/1089) I would therefore like to find the MaximumLikelihood solution of a customized PDF

I have a user defined one parameter PDF ρPDFns (given below, or described scientifically [here](http://cita.utoronto.ca/~codis/LSSFast.html)) which 
I can evaluate for any value of its parameter σ

```
pl = Plot[
   Table[ρPDFns[ρ, σ, -3/2], {σ, 0.1, 0.4, 0.05}] // Release, {ρ,
     0.1, 4}, PlotRange -> {0., 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I would like to estimate σ using a MaximumLikelihood approach.

I follow the documentation and define

```
Clear[myDistribution]; 
myDistribution[σ_] := 
 ProbabilityDistribution[ρPDFns[ρ, σ, -3/2], {ρ,
    1/10, 4}, Assumptions -> (σ > 0 && σ < 5/10)];
```

For instance

```
Plot[PDF[myDistribution[2/10], x], {x, 1/10, 4}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

works fine. I can of course generate a sample from this customized PDF

```
dat = RandomVariate[myDistribution[2/10], 500];
dat // Histogram
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**The problem**

> Maximumlikelihood estimation fails:

```
FindDistributionParameters[dat, 
 myDistribution[σ], {σ, 1/10},
 ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood", Method -> "NMaximize", 
   PrecisionGoal -> 1, MaxIterations -> 5}]
```

It produces this kind of error messages.

(* FindRoot::srect: Value [Sigma] in search specification {s$23324,[Sigma]} is not a number or array of numbers. >> *)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Question**

> How can I make [`FindDistributionParameters`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistributionParameters.html)
>   work on one parameter PDF which cannot be evaluated before the parameter has 
>   a numerical value.

---

Here is the code for the PDF.

```
ζ[x_, ν_] = 1/(1 - x/ν)^ν;
τ[y_, ν_] =  Module[{x}, x /. Solve[y == ζ[x, ν], x][[1]] // Quiet];
σ[r_, ns_, α_] = Sqrt[2 *1/((r)^(3 + ns + α) + (r)^(3 +   ns - α))];
ψ[y_, ν_, ns_, α_] = 1/2 τ[y, ν]^2/σ[y^(1/3), ns, α]^2;
dψ[y_, ν_, ns_, α_] = D[ψ[y, ν, ns, α], {y, 1}];
ddψ[y_, ν_: 21/13, ns_, α_] =  D[ψ[y, ν, ns, α], {y, 2}];
Lowlogrho[x_, s_, ν_, ns_, α_] =  1/Sqrt[2 Pi]*1/s*
   Sqrt[ddψ[x, ν, ns, α] + 
dψ[x, ν, ns, α]/x] Exp[-1/s^2*ψ[x, ν,   ns, α]];
Clear[logs0, logs1, logs2];
logs0[s_, ν_, ns_, α_] :=  logs0[s, ν, ns, α] = 
   Module[{β},  NIntegrate[  Lowlogrho[β, s, ν, ns, α], {β, 0.1,   10}]];
logs1[s_, ν_, ns_, α_] :=  logs1[s, ν, ns, α] = 
   Module[{β},     NIntegrate[ β Lowlogrho[β, s, ν, 
       ns, α], {β, 0.1, 10}]];
logs2[s_, ν_, ns_, α_] :=   logs2[s, ν, ns, α] = 
  Module[{β},  NIntegrate[ β^2 Lowlogrho[β, s, ν, 
      ns, α], {β, 0.1, 10}]]; Clear[effsiglog]; 
effsiglog[sig_, ν_, ns_, α_] := effsiglog[sig, ν, ns, α] = 
  Module[{s},  s /. FindRoot[logs0[s, ν, ns, α] logs2[s, ν, ns, α]/
         logs1[s, ν, ns, α]^2 == 1 + sig^2, {s, sig}] //Quiet];
Options[ρPDFns] = {ν -> 21/13, α -> 0};
Clear[ρPDFns]; ρPDFns[ρ_, sigma_, ns_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
 logs1[effsiglog[sigma, OptionValue[ν], ns, 
      OptionValue[α]], OptionValue[ν], ns, 
     OptionValue[α]]/
    logs0[effsiglog[sigma, OptionValue[ν], ns, 
       OptionValue[α]], OptionValue[ν], ns, 
      OptionValue[α]]^2 Lowlogrho[ρ*
     logs1[effsiglog[sigma, OptionValue[ν], ns, 
        OptionValue[α]], OptionValue[ν], ns, 
       OptionValue[α]]/
      logs0[effsiglog[sigma, OptionValue[ν], ns, 
        OptionValue[α]], OptionValue[ν], ns, 
       OptionValue[α]], 
    effsiglog[sigma, OptionValue[ν], ns, OptionValue[α]], 
    OptionValue[ν], ns, OptionValue[α]] // Quiet;
```

---

PS: a simpler, in my opinion equivalent test problem, is given in this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133392/1089).

Comment: I'm fairly sure that part of the problem is that part of the problem here is that during the processing of the problem, Mathematica is trying to symbolically evaluate functions that should only evaluate with numerical inputs. For example, your function `effsiglog` has a `FindRoot` in it, so it should never try to evaluate symbolically. To prevent this from happening, you can use the `_?NumericQ` filter pattern on your inputs: `effsiglog[sig__?NumericQ, ν__?NumericQ, ns__?NumericQ, α__?NumericQ] :=...` This alone may not solve the problem, but it might at least be a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't directly answer your question

> How can I make `FindDistributionParameters` work on a one parameter
>   PDF which cannot be evaluated before the parameter has a numerical
>   value?

but the maximum likelihood estimate can be obtained by first following @SjoerdSmit 's advice about using `?NumericQ` in the definition of the distribution:

```
myDistribution[σ_?NumericQ] := ProbabilityDistribution[ρPDFns[ρ, σ, -3/2],
  {ρ, 1/10, 4}, Assumptions -> (σ > 0 && σ < 5/10)]
```

followed by the use of the `LogLikelihood` function:

```
dat = RandomVariate[myDistribution[2/10], 500];
FindMaximum[{LogLikelihood[myDistribution[σ], dat], 0 < σ < 5/10}, {σ, 0.1}]
(* {124.317, {σ -> 0.198984}} *)
```

I don't know why `FindDistributionParameters` fails (even with the use of `?NumericQ`).